# Infinite Wall of images loaded from server, images can overlay

Tags: ios, graphics

I'm tring to build a public bathroom type of wall, where users can draw on.
I'm thinking of a infinite scroll space, where users can write graffiti, draw, etc.
I will need to save and then load "drawings" dynamically for others to see. I'm having trouble defining the structure of this component.

1. How can I do this and not load the whole view into memory (it can get very heavy)?
2. How do I calculate the content size if drawings/images are able to overlap (users will be able to draw over others' work, sort of like tagging an area)?

I was looking at `CATiledLayer`; not sure if this can help because of the overlapping.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1) When the user draws something, find its bounding box. Save just the pixels within the bounding box. Be sure to save them with a transparent background.

2) When the user runs the app, they'll have some sort of default view of the wall. Load only those images whose bounding boxes overlap the user's view of the wall. You'll probably want to sort the images in some way so you can quickly search them to see which have bounding boxes that overlap the current view.

3) As the user pans around the wall, load any images that have bounding boxes intersecting the new view area, and release any that you previously showed which have scrolled off.